# CRITICAL_SECTION in boost?

Tags: boost, mutex, critical-section

is there something in boost that translates to windows `CRITICAL_SECTION`?
`CRITICAL_SECTION` is a so called "user mode" mutex that uses spin locks instead of blocking and avoids expensive transitions to the kernel.

Answer (score -1):

Boost::Mutex is what you want, versions up to 1.34.1 used a win32 critical section, but new ones use a win32 event and locks. I don't know why - win32 mutexes are perfectly fine and as fast as an event (surely, he said...) unless you don't know if you need the crossprocess capability of them, or the sole-process limitation of a critical_section.

That said, chances are the performance implications of locking are mainly down to losing the rest of your threrad quantum, not necessarily kernel transitions.